# Mulitple 'clang: error: no such file or directory' after trying to build xcode project to phone

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

While trying to build my React Native project to test on my phone, I get multiple `clang: error: no such file or directory` for various files. In total I'm receiving around 11 separate errors which will be listed below.

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/bsoleimany/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{projectname}-bgjrrdizntqvulcjdjliktxgrpkw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTBlob.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/bsoleimany/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{projectname}-bgjrrdizntqvulcjdjliktxgrpkw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTAnimation.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/bsoleimany/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{projectname}-bgjrrdizntqvulcjdjliktxgrpkw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTActionSheet.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/bsoleimany/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{projectname}-bgjrrdizntqvulcjdjliktxgrpkw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTGeolocation.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/bsoleimany/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{projectname}-bgjrrdizntqvulcjdjliktxgrpkw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTImage.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/bsoleimany/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{projectname}-bgjrrdizntqvulcjdjliktxgrpkw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTLinking.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/bsoleimany/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{projectname}-bgjrrdizntqvulcjdjliktxgrpkw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTNetwork.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/bsoleimany/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{projectname}-bgjrrdizntqvulcjdjliktxgrpkw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTSettings.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/bsoleimany/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{projectname}-bgjrrdizntqvulcjdjliktxgrpkw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTText.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/bsoleimany/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{projectname}-bgjrrdizntqvulcjdjliktxgrpkw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTVibration.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/bsoleimany/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{projectname}-bgjrrdizntqvulcjdjliktxgrpkw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTWebSocket.a'
```

I have already tried switching `Build Settings` -> `Build Active Architecture Only` to `Yes` which gets rid of the errors above but then displays this new error

```
ld: library not found for -lRNPhotoView
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I looked around for a little but I couldn't find any information about the above error, does anyone know how to get rid of these?

Any suggestions on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please share the solution of this question if you got, because i am facing same issue while try to run app in simulator(Xcode 13.2). For the release schema is working fine but debug schema facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to ask a few clarification is are you trying to archive OR build a release version?
Answering that may help to see whats wrong BUT try unchecking the parallize build.

I encounter that error when i was trying:
 1. To archive
 2. My case was the build was trying to build at the same time and missed out some library when building. Deactivating that causes the build to run slower BUT making sure the React Library is build first, then the Xcode project. Hope this helps though i had this problem for 1 whole day.

[image]